# how do i get a reference to the a sub routine within a module

Tags: vb.net, methods, module, subroutine

I need to find out how to reference a Subroutine within another module by a reference. This is what I am trying to do:

```
Module Mod1

   sub_x(pass a reference to this module)

   Private Sub close_me()
       ' do something here
   End Sub

End Module

Module Mod2

    Public Sub sub_x(get the reference to the passed module)
      reference to passed module.close_me()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Sub_x will receive calls from several different modules. All of the calling modules will have a close_me() subroutine. So I need to know which module is calling sub_x so I know which one to close.

Comment: modules in vb are like `shared` functions in classes.  There is no concept of an instance of a module or 'closing' a module.  If you want that functionality, use classes without shared methods.

Comment: I'm not really closing the module. The close_me() function refers to something going on inside the module.

Comment: Just realize that this will not be thread safe unless you build it with some of the built-in techniques, such as `Sync`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Mod2:

```
Public Sub sub_x(ByVal closeModule As Action)
    closeModule()
End Sub
```

In Mod1:

```
Mod2.sub_x(AddressOf Mod1.close_me)
```

Comment: Thanks Joel, this looks like it should work, but it give me an error in Mod1 saying that Me is not valid within a Module.

Comment: Change it to the name of the module.

Comment: I can't use the module name either, but if I just leave it off, it seems to accept it without error. If I mouse over it, it shows the name of the module I am referencing. However, when I run it, it does not actually call the module. If I trace it out, and I show the value of closeModule in Mod2, it shows that it is indeed System.Action.

Comment: After further review, I see that removing the "Me" reference and leaving it blank gives me the value of -  {Method = {Void close_this_window()}} System.Action. I think the "Void" needs to be the name of my module. So I need to figure out how to pass it without error.

Comment: In the end this actually worked. I needed to leave off the "me" and "mod1" names and just use the name of the subroutine. Originally I did not include the "ByVal" reference in my parameters and it was causing it not to work, but once I included it, it started working. Thanks for your help.